# How to enhance my query with an index-match like statement?

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, array-formulas, google-sheets-query, gs-vlookup

[Link to sheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/12b9wjK8AoSl8L2ti1XK9Lrs4qEtkXphztLOhcrCcojs/edit?usp=sharing)
**Context:** with an API call I am getting pricelist data from Airtable into Sheets. In Airtable tables are linked, hence I am seeing the primary key generated by Airtable as opposed to the actual field data. The tables where I can find that data can be found in separate tabs created with the API call.
**Challenge:** I am trying to create a price list with a dropdown field that generates relevant data once a model is selected. This query is used for that:

```
=UNIQUE(QUERY(models,"SELECT F, E, R, R*(1-0.15), R*0.15, R*1.07 WHERE J = '"&$A$1&"' AND (F = 'rec99pY85FrcpKWmh' OR F ='reccliFdf3cbYeADx') AND F <> '' LABEL R 'Retail excl. VAT', R*(1-0.15) 'Store Price', R*0.15 'Margin', R*1.07 'Retail incl. VAT' FORMAT R '฿ ###,##0', R*(1-0.15) '฿ ###,##0', R*0.15 '฿ ###,##0', R*1.07 '฿ ###,##0' ",1))
```

I need to replace the strings under material and size with the corresponding labels. I can do that with this formula:

```
=SUBSTITUTE(B3,B3,index(indexBodySizes,match(B3:B13,idSizes,0),6))
```

for sizes and

```
=SUBSTITUTE(A3,A3,index(indexBodyMaterials,match(A3:A13,idMaterials,0),1))
```

for materials.
**Question:** How can I combine the functionality of these individual sub-solutions into on query?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
=ARRAYFORMULA({UNIQUE(QUERY(models, 
 "select F,E,R,R*(1-0.15),R*0.15,R*1.07 
  where  J = '"&$A$1&"' 
    and (F = 'rec99pY85FrcpKWmh' 
     or  F = 'reccliFdf3cbYeADx') 
    and  F <> '' 
  label  R 'Retail excl. VAT',R*(1-0.15)'Store Price',R*0.15'Margin',R*1.07'Retail incl. VAT' 
  format R '฿ ###,##0',R*(1-0.15) '฿ ###,##0',R*0.15 '฿ ###,##0',R*1.07 '฿ ###,##0'", 1)), 
 {"Sizes"; IFERROR(VLOOKUP(INDEX(UNIQUE(QUERY(models, 
 "select F,E,R,R*(1-0.15),R*0.15,R*1.07 
  where  J = '"&$A$1&"' 
    and (F = 'rec99pY85FrcpKWmh' 
     or  F = 'reccliFdf3cbYeADx') 
    and  F <> '' 
  label  R'',R*(1-0.15)'',R*0.15'',R*1.07''", 0)),,2), Sizes!A:G, 7, 0))},
 {"Materials"; IFERROR(VLOOKUP(INDEX(UNIQUE(QUERY(models, 
 "select F,E,R,R*(1-0.15),R*0.15,R*1.07 
  where  J = '"&$A$1&"' 
    and (F = 'rec99pY85FrcpKWmh' 
     or  F = 'reccliFdf3cbYeADx') 
    and  F <> '' 
  label  R'',R*(1-0.15)'',R*0.15'',R*1.07''", 0)),,1), Materials!A:B, 2, 0))}})
```

[image: 0]

---

```
=ARRAYFORMULA({{"Material"; IFERROR(VLOOKUP(INDEX(UNIQUE(QUERY(models, 
 "select F,E 
  where  J = '"&$A$1&"' 
    and (F = 'rec99pY85FrcpKWmh' 
     or  F = 'reccliFdf3cbYeADx') 
    and  F <> ''", 0)),,1), Materials!A:B, 2, 0))},
{"Size"; IFERROR(VLOOKUP(INDEX(UNIQUE(QUERY(models, 
 "select F,E
  where  J = '"&$A$1&"' 
    and (F = 'rec99pY85FrcpKWmh' 
     or  F = 'reccliFdf3cbYeADx') 
    and  F <> ''", 0)),,2), Sizes!A:G, 7, 0))},
UNIQUE(QUERY(models, 
 "select R,R*(1-0.15),R*0.15,R*1.07 
  where  J = '"&$A$1&"' 
    and (F = 'rec99pY85FrcpKWmh' 
     or  F = 'reccliFdf3cbYeADx') 
    and  F <> '' 
  label  R 'Retail excl. VAT',R*(1-0.15)'Store Price',R*0.15'Margin',R*1.07'Retail incl. VAT' 
  format R '฿ ###,##0',R*(1-0.15) '฿ ###,##0',R*0.15 '฿ ###,##0',R*1.07 '฿ ###,##0'", 1))})
```

[image: 0]

Comment: Thank you, player0! I am digesting your solution. Could you comment back on my observations?
1. You have used {[],[],[]} to put the columns together.
2. With a Vlookup you are returning the value searched for in the first or second column respectively from the corresponding materials or size range.

If this is correct, I thought I could easily swap {Sizes} and {Materials} in front of the table and delete F,E in the first query. The last part is true. But moving the {Sizes } and {Materials} part seem to break the formula. I wonder why? I just want to understand the solution better. Thanks.

Comment: yes, you are mostly right the array is `{(fx1), {"header1";(fx2)}, {"header2";(fx3)}}` so if you want to swap it around it would be: `{{"header2";(fx3)}, {"header1";(fx2)}, (fx1)}` therefore: https://i.stack.imgur.com/zMoBL.png

Comment: :-) of course, that makes all the difference in the world. I had completely overlooked the semi-colon. Thanks a million, this advances my capabilities to wrangle some data a lot. Have a great day!